# Angular Material Table With Editable Fields

Tags: angular5, angular-material2, angular-forms

I am using angular material to create a table from data in the form of arrays. This all works beautifully. The problem I am having is that the fields themselves need to be form fields. They need to be populated from the data, and yet editable. Also a new row with blank fields should be fillable and persisted. What I am finding is that although the row data populates, the values never make it into the form fields themselves, or the form fields are all populated by the first record only. There is something wrong with the way I am referencing the field values, but I can't see what it is. So, here's the table in html:

```
<form #a="ngForm" >
  <mat-table #approvalsTable [dataSource]="approvalsDataSource"
             #approvalsSort="matSort" matSort matSortActive="description"
             matSortDirection="asc" style="width:900px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Description</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
        <input type="text"
               name="description" [(ngModel)]="element.description" [value]="element.description">
        {{element.description}}

      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="approvalNumber">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Approval No.</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
        <input type="text"
               name="approvalNumber" [(ngModel)]="element.approvalNumber" [value]="element.approvalNumber">
        {{element.approvalNumber}}

      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="expires">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Expiration Date</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index">
        <input type="text"
               name="expires" [(ngModel)]="element.expires" [value]="element.expires">
        {{element.expires}}

      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header disabled>Actions</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;" style="text-align:right;">

        <div style="min-width:9em;">
          <button (click)="addApproval(a.value)"><img src="../../assets/images/icons/plus.svg" width="20px" height="20px"/>
          </button>
          <button (click)="deleteApproval(a.value)"><img src="../../assets/images/icons/garbage.svg" width="20px" height="20px"/>
          </button>
          <button (click)="saveApproval(a.value)"><img src="../../assets/images/icons/checked-1.svg" width="20px" height="20px"/>
          </button>
        </div>

      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="approvalsDisplayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: approvalsDisplayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</form>
```

...and here's the component code that fills the form and actions the buttons

```
  @ViewChild('approvalsSort') public approvalsSort: MatSort;

  APPROVALS_ELEMENT_DATA: Approval[] = [];
  approvalsDisplayedColumns = ['description', 'approvalNumber', 'expires', 'actions'];
  approvalsDataSource;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUser = this.authenticationService.returnCurrentUser();

    // 1. Establish the organisation
    // an organisaiton may already exist, either being routed

    if (this.route.data) {
      this.route.data
        .subscribe(({ organisation }) => {
          this.organisation = organisation;
        });

    } else {
      // or is attached to the current user
      this.organisation = this.currentUser.organisation;
    }

    if (!this.organisation) {
      this.organisation = new Organisation();
    }

    // 4. Initialise the tables
    this.makeBlankApproval();

    this.render(this.organisation);    
  }

  render(o: Organisation) {
    console.log(this.organisation.approvals); // this is the console.log!!!
    this.APPROVALS_ELEMENT_DATA = o.approvals;
    this.approvalsDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Approval>(this.APPROVALS_ELEMENT_DATA);
    this.approvalsDataSource.sort = this.approvalsSort;    
  }

  makeBlankApproval() {
    const approval: Approval = makeApproval('', '', '');
    this.organisation.approvals.push(approval);
  }

  addApproval(form: any) {
    let foundEmpty: boolean = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.organisation.approvals.length; i++) {
      const appToUpdate = this.organisation.approvals[i];
      if (appToUpdate.description === '' && appToUpdate.approvalNumber === '' && appToUpdate.expires === '') {
        foundEmpty = true;
      }
    }
    if (!foundEmpty) {
      this.makeBlankApproval();
    }
    this.render(this.organisation);
  }

  deleteApproval(form: any) {
    console.log(form);
  }

  saveApproval(form: any) {
    this.render(this.organisation);
  }
```

Now, to exercise the case, what I have done is:
1. fill in the first row with some dummy data
2. save it (using saveApproval(form))
3. add a new row, using addApproval()

What I expect is two rows in the table with the first one blank, the second with the saved field data filled in.

What I get are two blank fields.

The console logs provide an interesting story, so here's the results of the testing:

1. Initial form load:
   [image]
   [image]

Fill in and hit saveApproval
[image]
[image]

Hit addApproval
[image]
[image]

So, as you can see, the dataSource looks good, the actions look good, the element fields are right (you can see them in the output), its just the form fields themselves not getting the data populated in them. It may also be that all rows are being populated with the data from row 0 - I'm not sure.

As an interesting additional observation: the element view in dev tools shows this:

[image: picture of the description element in the second row (1)]

ng-reflect-model has the value in it, but in this view there is no value attribute present, yet it is specified through the [value] directive, or so I thought. i have also tried ng-value and just the plain old value attribute.

So, how do you get the right values in to the right form inputs on the right rows?

Comment: well, it looks like the interblags don't know - I eventually solved this by implementing a plain old html table - it has the advantage in that it works.